# How to group coordinates by distance

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates, openlayers

I have a set of points (coordinates), and I can calculate de distance from each to all.

But I want to group the points that are near each other (lets say, less than 500m).

```
  PointsCoords =[
  ["lat01, lng01", "P01"],
  ["lat02, lng02", "P02"],
  ["lat03, lng03", "P03"],
  ["lat04, lng04", "P04"],
  ["lat05, lng05", "P05"],
  ["lat06, lng06", "P06"],
  ["lat07, lng07", "P07"]
  ];
```

I make the calculations and I know now that for distance less than 500m I have the pairs:

```
varAllPairs = [
[P01, P03], //450m
[P02, P03], //200m
[P05, P06]] //350m
```

But, how do I group them like:

```
varClusterGroups = [P01,P02,P03], [P05,P06]
```

(I know that P01 to P02 is more than 500m, but for now its better than nothing... is there a better way to find a REAL cluster of points?)

How can I make the group (varClusterGroups) with javascript or jquery (or underscore)?

Or maybe a solution 2: Get all the coordinates and apply an algorithm that gives me the clustered groups

Tks

EDIT:
I really don't know the right criteria, but what I need is to receive an alert when I have 2 or more points close enough (this is to detect when 2 or more vehicles are close enough [less than X m from each other], when they are not suppose to), so I don´t have a "center point" pre-defined. I just want to have the information that vehicles 01,03,04 and 05,07,08 and 09,15 are "grouped". It can be the possibility than one or more points belongs to other group, but I think that if two groups have common point it should be converted to one group.

Comment: what are the cluster criteria? do they need just one common "center point" where all others can be 500m away? Do the clusters need to be biggest possible? is there a possiblity for one point to belong to multiple clusters?

Comment: Even if some vehicles in that group then are more than 1km from each other?? Alo this was a suggestion for an edit... people don't want to read comments for tze whole question

Comment: Have a look at http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster.html

Comment: @Christophe Roussy: I don´t want map cluster (because it depends on the zoom of map/pixel distance). I need something "like" strategy-cluster, but for JavaScript.