# Merge Arrays by common values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really can´t figure this out.

How do I turn this:

```
varAllMix = [[1,2], [3,4], [1,4], [5,6], [7,2], [8,5], [9,10], [11,6]];
```

To this:

```
varComGroup = [[1,2,3,4,7],[5,6,8,11],[9,10]]
```

For example: `[1,2,3,4,7]` is resulted from merging `[1,2], [3,4], [1,4], [7,2]` by the common values:

```
[1,2] + [1,4] -> [1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 4] + [3,4] -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4] + [7, 2] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
```

Comment: What are the rules for grouping the tuples?

Comment: Connected integers, each tuple is an edge ?

Comment: Oh right, that's cool. Should be easy enough to write a simple algo for that :) like .. O2? :D

Comment: There is a concept called `disjoint set`.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is...

Comment: if a value exist in more than one array, group them together, so if var1=[car,blue]; var2=[ball,blue], then varAll=[car,blue,ball,blue] (removing duplicated we have varAll=[car,blue,ball])

Comment: This looks like a homework problem to me. Questions on StackOverflow, even intellectually challenging ones, must demonstrate "a minimal understanding of the problem being solved," which this one does not. Please take a stab at solving it yourself, and come back here when you have a specific issue you need help with. For further guidelines on asking effective questions, see http://stackoverflow.com.about

Comment: @Bitamina you should call it `merge` instead of `group`

Comment: I would like to know how you managed to get a 7 in group 1...

Comment: @Pinocchio: His last update seems to show how that works.  `[1,2]` and `[7,2]` match because they both contain `2`.

Comment: ooh, so after you find a duplicate you have to wait for a new number to split the groups?

Comment: Well, I'm too old for homework. I learn all I know from javascript in forums/site like this. In my code I get an array of pairs of vehicles that are less than x meters from each other, and I what to group/merge them... so if (A< X meters of B and C < X meters of B, then group/merge them in (A,B,C)...
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696218/how-to-group-coordinates-by-distance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696218/how-to-group-coordinates-by-distance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it quite efficiently (and does even support more than two values per `allMix` tuple):

```
var AllMix = [[1,2], [3,4], [1,4], [5,6], [7,2], [8,5], [9,10], [11,6]];

var ComGroup = [],
    lookup = {}; // a lookup table for sets in ComGroup per value
for (var i=0; i<AllMix.length; i++) {
    var sets = [], // sets in ComGroup that contain one of the tuple values
        add = []; // new, yet unknown values
    for (var j=0, l=AllMix[i].length; j<l; j++) {
        var val = AllMix[i][j];
        if (val in lookup) {
            if (sets.indexOf(lookup[val]) == -1)
                sets.push(lookup[val]);
        } else
            add.push(val);
    }
    var merge = sets.shift(), // the set to merge into (or add values)
        addFrom; // the number of values in merge that are known to lookup
    if (merge) {
        addFrom = merge.length;
        if (add.length) sets.push(add); // add the new values to the merged sets
    } else { // no set was found in lookup that contains numbers from the tuple
        ComGroup.push(merge = add); // make the new numbers the new set
        addFrom = 0;
    }
    for (var j=0; j<sets.length; j++) // merge all sets into merge
        merge.push.apply(merge, sets[j].splice(0)); // and empty them
    for (var l=merge.length; addFrom<l; addFrom++) // for all new numbers
        lookup[merge[addFrom]] = merge; // update the set lookup table
}
ComGroup = ComGroup.filter(function(set) {
    // sort each set numerically and remove the empty ones
    return set.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;}).length;
});
```

Comment: Fantastic!!! Working great in FF
Except in IE8.... What could be the problem?

Comment: That IE does not support the [`filter` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - but you can easily shim that, or use a plain loop to remove empty sets from `ComGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the result incrementally by adding pairs

```
m = {}; // map from an element to the connected component
result = [];

for (var i=0; i < lists.lenght; i++) {
    var a = lists[i][0], b = lists[i][1];
    var ca = m[a];
    var cb = m[b];
    if (ca && cb) {
        if (ca !== cb) {
            // two connected components got merged
            for (var bi=0; bi < cb.lenght; bi++) {
                ca.push(cb[bi]);
                m[cb[bi]] = ca;
            }
            cb.splice();
        }
    } else if (ca) {
        ca.push(b); // extending connected component of a
    } else if (cb) {
        cb.push(a); // extending connected component of b
    } else {
        // create a new connected component
        result.push(m[a] = m[b] = [a, b]);
    }
}

// remove leftovers from merge operations
result = result.filter(function(x){return x.length;});
```

Comment: This looks quite like my solution but without support for multiple elements in an `allMix` tuple :-) Btw, you forgot `m[b] = ca` and `m[a] = cb` in the extending-a-set part.

Comment: @Bergi: whoops, you're right. Fixed. I didn't check your answer first but indeed seems the same idea. I didn't consider multiple elements in input because it would be a pointless complication if they are not present (was a coincidence they were all pairs?).

Comment: I just tried to be as generic as possible to avoid code duplication (I needed a little challenge) :-) I hope it didn't got too complicated…